# How to output dropped csv lines into file in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm currently importing csv data into ES and filtering out lines that do not match my regex pattern for certain fields using drop {}.
How do I log the dropped lines into a file which I can analyse later.

```
 if [email] !~ /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/ {
      drop { }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the event it will not be sent to any outputs, or even go through any later filters. You will have to tag the event if the regexp matches (mutate+add_tag) and then use a conditional in the output section

```
filter { if [email] !~ /.../ { mutate { add_tag => [ "someTag" ] } } }
output { if "someTag" in [tags] { file {...} } else { elasticsearch {...} } }
```